# Ruby Gem Executables Slow to Run

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

Some of the gems I have installed take an unreasonable amount of time to simply report their version (or do anything). Since this behavior seems limited to my machine, I'm inclined to believe it's an environment problem.

My Output:

```
$time orb -v
orb_archetyper v2.2.0
real    0m53.144s  # 53 seconds!
user    0m52.616s
sys     0m0.643s
```

Coworker's Output:

```
$ time orb -v
 orb_archetyper v2.2.0
 real    0m4.707s
 user    0m4.434s
 sys     0m0.269s
```

Ruby Version:

```
rvm rubies

jruby-1.6.5 [ x86_64 ]
jruby-1.7.4 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-1.8.7-p334 [ i686 ]
ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.0.0-p481 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Is there some kind of search being performed by Rubygems that would account for this slowness?

Comment: Could you run the version command in one terminal and watch `top` in another? Could be other things hogging system resources.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After watching top, Ruby starts and takes 90%-100% cpu for the duration of the `orb -v` command. No other processes jump out as suspicious. Additionally, performance for everything else on my box seems fine.

Comment: Odd.... hate to sound cliche but, "Did you try turning it off and on again"? I have no idea why ruby would be causing that kind of error. Have you reinstalled the offending gems?

Comment: On what kind of storage are your gems installed (and ruby itself)?

Comment: I have reinstalled the gem. It seemed to have no effect. @moritz my gems are installed on SSD.